# Setting CSS for Google Charts with generated div ids

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-visualization

I have a page that projects a series of charts with ids generated with `Mako` template language in `Python`.

The chart `div`s are defined like in below.

```
% for step_id in step_ids:
      ...
    <div id="step_chart_div${step_id}" style='width: 900px; height: 500px;'></div>
      ...
% endfor
```

I want to separate the style part from `HTML`, so I assigned a class name for the div, and put the `style` in a separate `.css` file like

```
.step_charts{ /* style.css */
    width: 900px; height: 500px;
}


% for step_id in step_ids:
      ...
    <div class="step_charts" id="step_chart_div${step_id}"></div>
      ...
% endfor
```

, but it shortens the height of the chart.

At least it allocates the height of 500px for the `div`, without `style` it is even shorter, but the size of the chart is short like that without `style`.

How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: You should not see any difference in the height of the chart.  Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?  Someting I can run in jsfiddle/codepen/jsbin/etc would be most helpful in helping you fix this.

Comment: @asgallant Thanks. The example should be trivial, but I don't think I can use `Mako` template language in `jsfiddle` to generate `div` `id`s. Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: You can't use any server-side features in jsfiddle, but you don't need to.  A simple, single-chart example should suffice (which you could put in a div with a fixed id: `<div class="step_charts" id="step_chart_div1"></div>`, as that is what your browser is seeing after the server code runs).